# How to redirect the send command output in expect script to a string

Tags: python, bash, ssh, expect, send

I have an expect script that will login to the remote server and execute a python script. Is there a way to read the output that python script produces (that is I would like to read output of send "python pythonscript.py arg1\r"). I tried `expect_out(0,string)` but it does not display the output that python script produces. Please suggest ideas

expectscript.exp

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

eval spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no user@******
expect "Password:"
send "password\r"
expect "$username$"
set prompt ":|#|\\\$"
set timeout -1
send "cd /Users/username/Documents/folder/\r"
send "python pythonscript.py arg1\r"
expect $prompt
```

Comment: `export SSHPASS='password'; sshpass -e ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no user@****** 'cd /Users/username/Documents/folder/ && python pythonscript.py arg1' >stdout.txt`?

Comment: Thanks! This works. I tried to do same to run .sh script from the same remote server location but it does not work. Please help
export SSHPASS='password'; sshpass -e ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no user@****** 'cd /Users/username/Documents/folder/ && ./script.sh arg1'

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). This page is intended for programming questions.

Comment: Note that you don't need to `eval` that spawn command. There's nothing in there that requires a 2nd pass through the Tcl parser.